# How can I enter into a specific query in mongoDB,

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get the voting record for specific bills in congress, this is the structure of my mongoose model:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc496d1fee37b184efaaf73"),
    "bill_id" : "hr312-116",
    "title" : "To reaffirm the Mashpee Wampanoag Tribe reservation, and for other purposes.",
    "sponsorState" : "MA",
    "sponsorParty" : "D",
    "summary" : "Mashpee Wampanoag Tribe Reservation Reaffirmation Act This bill reaffirms the Mashpee Wampanoag Tribe reservation as trust land in Massachusetts. In addition, the bill requires actions, including actions pending in federal court, relating to the land to be dismissed.",
    "primarySubject" : "Mashpee Wampanoag Tribe Reservation Reaffirmation Act This bill reaffirms the Mashpee Wampanoag Tribe reservation as trust land in Massachusetts. In addition, the bill requires actions, including actions pending in federal court, relating to the land to be dismissed.",
    "introducedDate" : "2019-01-08",
    "latestMAction" : "Read the second time. Placed on Senate Legislative Calendar under General Orders. Calendar No. 92.",
    "votingRecord" : [ 
        {
            "person" : 400440,
            "state" : "AK",
            "district" : 0,
            "vote" : "No",
            "name" : "Rep. Don Young [R]",
            "party" : "Republican"
        }, .... ]
```

this is what i'm trying and the response is undefined:

```
findAllVotes: function(req, res) {

        db
            .find(req.query)
            .sort({ state: 0 })
            .select("votingRecord")
            .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
            .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out your state in sort function.in collection your filed state:'AK' and in sort you providing state:0

Comment: I got it working, probably had to do with the sorting but also y had some problems in my routes, i made it this way: ```    findAllVotes: function(req, res) {
        console.log("Back");
        db
            .find()
            .select("votingRecord")
            .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
            .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
    }         ```            Thanks for your help!!